# AWS CDK: Don't build assets when running 'cdk bootstrap' command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I bundle my assets using Docker & Dockerfile:

```
Code.from_docker_build(
    path='/path',
    build_args={},
)
```

Every time I run `cdk deploy` or `cdk bootstrap` the code bundling is triggered.

- On the `cdk deploy` action code bundling makes sense.
- But on the `cdk bootstrap` command the code bundling should not be triggered. Is there any way to avoid code bundling during `cdk bootstrap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-bootstrap): If issued with no arguments... the cdk bootstrap command synthesizes the current app and bootstraps the environments its stacks will be deployed to.

So to have `cdk bootstrap` skip the synth step, (a) bootstrap from outside the app directory and (b) explicitly provide the account and region:

```sh
cdk bootstrap ACCOUNT-NUMBER/REGION # e.g.
cdk bootstrap 1111111111/us-east-1
```